# Improve Mysql Select Query Performance

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a mysql table with 155+ columns.
I am running a select query with some `case` conditions and some `Where` conditions, The query is giving correct result but the only thing is speed. The query is taking around 50-60sec in execution.
I am using almost **25** columns in my where and case condition.
is there any why I can Optimize the execution time?
I have created index for **6** columns out of **25** columns.
is it good practice to create index for all **25** columns?

Please Suggest
Thank You!!!

Comment: You are asking for a specific advice without telling us the specifics (the code and data). At the moment all I can say: it depends on your code and your data. The answers for the duplicate question will provide you with guidance and direction as to whatindexes to create.